# Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I use Visual Studio 2010.
Now I'm testing a procedure which loads data from a file.
Something went wrong, I don't remember what the compiler was angry about.
Anyway, now I my procedure is not executed at all,
it is as if ignored.

And I get this:

```
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Гость\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\coursework\Debug\coursework.exe', Symbols loaded.
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x4aa50000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'coursework.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x4aa50000'
'coursework.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x49fe0000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'coursework.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x49fe0000
```

I tried to look through debugger options, but have fixed nothing.

Now I have an idea of killing all the files the Debug directory. The one which is in the same folder as sln file. Well, there is another Debug directory where cpp files are situated.

Am I right that this may help? Have I chosen the right Debug directory (in it there are 3 files: exe, ilk, pdb).

ADDED LATER

This is an extract which seems to have caused problems.

```
ifstream myfile ("grablevskij.txt");
    delete[] pointer;

    AR_POINT ar_point = {NULL, 0, 0};   
    POINT * tmp_point = new POINT();

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {       
        string line;
        while (myfile.good() )
        {
            getline (myfile, line);
            int x_first = line.find('(') + 1;
            int x_last = line.find(',') - 1;
            string x_substr = line.substr(x_first, x_last);
            int tmp_x = atoi(x_substr.c_str());

            int y_first = line.find(',') + 1;
            int y_last = line.find(')') - 1;
            string y_substr = line.substr(y_first, y_last);
            int tmp_y = atoi(y_substr.c_str());             
            ar_point.occup++;           
            (*tmp_point).id = ar_point.occup;
            (*tmp_point).x = tmp_x;
            (*tmp_point).y = tmp_y;
            ar_point.p = new_point(ar_point.p, tmp_point, ar_point.occup);          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `    delete[] pointer;` just a random line that belongs to some code before this section of code? It doesn't seem to belong in the code-snippet you have posted.

Comment: well, when I load data from the file, I want to remove all the prevous data.

Comment: Ok, fair enough - it just looks a bit random at this place, since there is no other mention of "pointer" in the posted code.

Comment: well, I'm pretty new to C++. To tell the truth, this warries me a bit. With the new operator I breed some POINT structs. They are situated somewhere in the heap. New returns *POINT. And I maintain the array of pointers to pointers to keep the information where my points are situated. When I want to load the file, I make sure that the user really wants to replace existing data. Then I delete the array of pointers to pointers. This is delete[] pointer (pointer is **POINT). But what troubles me is whether all my POINT structures are still kept in the heap. Could you suggest me anything?

Comment: Would really help to see more of the code...

Comment: This is the whole solution: http://sdrv.ms/VTDyI7 User: 1) inputs points with any coordinates; 2) saves the points to a file; 3) loads the points from a file; 4) deletes points.

Comment: What do you mean "this is the whole solution"? It's not ALL the code, I can tell that because there are variable declarations missing for one thing.

Comment: pardon, please. I mechanically pressed enter when finished a sentence.

Comment: @Pepperwork Have you tried running your VS session as Administrator on the box? Downloading adding symbols to the symbol set on Vista and later is an admin-only thing the last time i checked. If you can "Run as Administrator" the settings of your VS startup icon, try it (unless you already *are* an admin, at which point I'm somewhat befuddled unless you aren't setup to download symbols from MS, which is possible too. Not sure of your config).

Comment: thank you. it is working. well, maybe you can suggest me anything atout that cleaning memory matter?